# Box with a line in the centre

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, diagrams, geometry, mathtools

[image: box multiplication diagram]

How can I do this for box multiplication in LaTeX?

Comment: An attempt of a code example would help this problem.

Comment: Shouldn't "bow" in the title be "box"?

Comment: Since you've tagged tikz-pgf, I would suggest looking at the TikZ manual here: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf -- given the drawing you want is so simple, you can probably just scan through the pictures in the first 3 chapters and find what you need. Learn about `\draw` and `\node`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I've edited the posting's title to fix the typo you identified.

Answer (score 1):

I take it that it's important that the boxed cells have the same width. To achieve this result, I suggest you employ an `array` environment with the fixed-width `w` column type for the right-hand column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{calc}  % for '\widthof' macro
\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt} % for a less-cramped "look"

\begin{document} 

$\begin{array}{ c | c | wc{\widthof{240}} |}
    \mc{} & \mc{40} & \mc{1} \\
    \cline{2-3}
    6     & 240     & 6  \\
    \cline{2-3}
\end{array}$ 

\end{document}
```